# get row id dataTable primefaces

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I have a dataTable something like the code above, as you can see, im using the event rowSelectedcheckBox, there is any way to know the row that was clicked and based on that information disabled the row completely?

```
 <p:dataTable id="tblTipoCarteraGeneric" style="text-align:left;" 
                     value="#{alertasPredefinidasModel.tipoCarteraDTOs}"
                     var="tipoCartera"
                     rows="15" paginator="true"
                     emptyMessage="empty"
                     paginatorAlwaysVisible="true" 
                     paginatorPosition="bottom"                         
                     selection="#{alertasPredefinidasModel.elementoSeleccionado.tipoCarteraDTOs}"
                     rowKey="#{tipoCartera.tipoCarteraDTO.tipocarteraID}"
                     rendered="#{alertasPredefinidasModel.isTipoCartera()}">

            <p:ajax event="rowSelectCheckbox" update=":form:tblTipoCarteraGeneric, :form:messages" 
                    listener="#{alertasPredefinidasController.onRowSelected}"/>
            <p:ajax event="rowUnselectCheckbox" update=":form:tblTipoCarteraGeneric, :form:messages" 
                    listener="#{alertasPredefinidasController.onRowUnselected}"/>

            <p:column selectionMode="multiple" styleClass="selection-column no-all"
                      disabledSelection="#{alertasPredefinidasModel.modoDetalle}"/>

            <p:column headerText="Tipo de cartera" styleClass="wrappedText" >
                <h:outputText id="inTxtCol1" value="#{tipoCartera.tipoCarteraDTO.nombre}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Valor del abono" styleClass="wrappedText" rendered="#{alertasPredefinidasModel.isTipoCarteraConValorOpcion2()}">
                <h:inputText id="inTxtCol2" value="#{tipoCartera.parametro1}" style="width:100%" 
                             disabled="#{alertasPredefinidasModel.modoDetalle}"/>
                <pe:tooltip myPosition="top center" atPosition="bottom right" for="inTxtCol2"                                       
                            value="#{tooltips.obtainToolTip('parametrizarAlertasPredefinidas', 'inTxtCol2', 'es', 'itac.SIT-Core-Middleware-Sarlaft-WAR.tooltip')} "/>
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Porcentaje superior al valor del abono" styleClass="wrappedText" rendered="#{alertasPredefinidasModel.isTipoCarteraConValorOpcion2()}">
                <h:inputText id="inTxtCol3" value="#{tipoCartera.parametro2}" style="width:100%" 
                             disabled="#{alertasPredefinidasModel.modoDetalle}"/>
                <pe:tooltip myPosition="top center" atPosition="bottom right" for="inTxtCol3"                                       
                            value="#{tooltips.obtainToolTip('parametrizarAlertasPredefinidas', 'inTxtCol3', 'es', 'itac.SIT-Core-Middleware-Sarlaft-WAR.tooltip')} "/>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
```

Comment: What you want ? Do you want to disable selected row/ rows? Once you disable a row , you can't enable that row/rows. Is this your requirement?

Comment: Just like a "toggle" (when checked, will activate the input Text; when not, will be deactivated)

Answer (score 1):

I think this will fulfill your requirement. I add one extra attribute `styleClass="tblTipoCarteraGeneric"` to your `<p:dataTable>` and add two `<p:ajax>` with events `page`(because after page change to keep previous page's user interaction record as same) and `toggleSelect`(if user select header checkbox instead of using singe chek box of each row).

Suppose if your `<p:dataTable>` is wrapped like this :

```
<h:form>
<p:dataTable id="tblTipoCarteraGeneric" styleClass="tblTipoCarteraGeneric" ......>
    <p:ajax event="rowSelectCheckbox" oncomplete="abcd()" />
    <p:ajax event="page" oncomplete="abcd()" />
    <p:ajax event="toggleSelect" oncomplete="abcd()" />

    <p:column></p:column>
    ..
    ..
    ..
    <p:column></p:column>
</p:dataTable>
<h:outputScript>var abcd = function(){

    $('div.tblTipoCarteraGeneric >div > table > tbody > tr').each(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('ui-state-highlight')){
            $(this).css({'pointer-events': 'none'});
        } else {
        $(this).css({'pointer-events': 'auto'});
        }
    });
    };
</h:outputScript>
</form>
```

Comment: thanks for your response, I would prefer a solution more in the primefaces way (i.e no hardcoded javascript)

Comment: @Chechus According to me there are no attribute in `<p:dataTable>` by which you can disable, enable a row. So there is no possible way to disable, enable a `<p:dataTable>`'s row without using javascript. If you find any better way please let me know. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

You can use rowIndex attribute of Datatable. You can use rowIndex in StyleClass and bind on click call a javascript method. Get the row through its class which will have rowIndex.

You Can also refer this

[Primefaces example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionInstant.jsf)